# Google Bigquery group by only one element but selecting multiple

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having a problem with google big query. I'll be using the public shakespear dataset as an example. I want to get the maximum word_count of all rows. And the belonging corpus. With normal sql this will work.

```
SELECT MAX(word_count) as w, corpus
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
```

But google bigquery wants all non-agregates to eb in the GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT MAX(word_count) as w, corpus
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
GROUP BY corpus
```

But then I get the maximum word_count of every corpus. I only want one result like:

```
 w    corpus
995   hamlet
```

Please help me I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way to do it is to use scalar subquery in WHERE clause, i.e.

```
SELECT word_count, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
WHERE word_count = (SELECT MAX(word_count) FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare])
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind found it:

```
SELECT r.w, s.corpus
FROM (SELECT MAX(word_count) as w
      FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]) as r
INNER JOIN [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] as s
ON r.w == s.word_count
```